Postgres Select Row From Group With Opposite Sort Order
I have a Postgres table foobar with the following schema:
id: integer
group: integer
foo: integer
bar: integer
timestamp: integer

I keep track of updates to various groups, and those updates mutate the foo and bar properties. Every time I receive an update, I store the timestamp.
Here's an example value I could have in the databse:
+------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
| "id" | "group" | "foo" | "bar" | "timestamp" |
+------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
| 1    | 1       | 10    | 20    | 1           |
| 2    | 1       | 11    | 19    | 2           |
| 3    | 1       | 10    | 20    | 3           |
| 4    | 1       | 10    | 20    | 4           |
+------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+

Oftentimes, the updates I receive are identical. A particularly critical piece of information I'm trying to extract is when I first received the combination of values that is current — but not for the first time ever, but rather the first update after which there haven't been any changes.
A naïve approach would be the following query:
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("group", foo, bar) *
FROM foobar
ORDER BY "group", foo, bar, timestamp DESC;

However, that query would return the last row, which has the latest timestamp. If I switch timestamp to ASC, I would get the very first row, because I have seen the exact foo/bar value combination prior to the update at timestamp 2.
The intuitive thing would have been to simply move the timestamp DESC sort command prior to foo, but Postgres does not allow that. Something like MySQL's HAVING operation could also have come in handy, but Postgres unfortunately doesn't support that.
An incredibly inefficient approach I could take is programmatically iterate through each group, get the latest row, and then fetch all rows in descending timestamp order and stop as soon as I observe a change, but it seems that letting a database do this sort of operation would be wiser.
I am quite certain that I'm missing something obvious, but would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Postgres supports HAVING, see https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-having/

I am a bit confused. What/why is your expected output? One/zero records per group?

That's a gaps-and-islands problem.
You can compare each row's (foo,bar) to previous row's using lag(). The window definition lets you only check those coming from the same group, in ascending order.
From that, you can get the latest "changing update" per group with a distinct on() or the 1=row_number()over w, as already described by @Stefanov.sm.
Demo at db<>fiddle:
select distinct on("group") id,"group",foo,bar,"timestamp"
from (select *,coalesce(   foo<>lead(foo)over w1
                        or bar<>lead(bar)over w1,true) is_diff_from_prev
      from foobar
      window w1 as (partition by "group" order by "timestamp" desc))_
where is_diff_from_prev
order by "group","timestamp" desc;




id
group
foo
bar
timestamp




3
1
10
20
3



For each group, this starts from the latest record and seeks the first one that changed either value. It takes around 3s on 200k rows with 4k groups, 7% of which have duplicate, non-changing updates among the most recent rows.

Yes, this is among the kinds of problems for which window functions (such as lag) are well suited.

Thank you so much for your answer, @Zegarek! This works perfectly, and I should be able to adjust it to my real-world scenario relatively easily :)

A way to solve your issue would be this:
select fb1."group", fb1."foo", fb1."bar", min(fb1."timestamp") as "timestamp"
from foobar fb1
left join foobar fb2
on fb1."group" = fb2."group" and
   fb2."timestamp" > fb1."timestamp" and
   (fb2."foo" <> fb1."foo" or fb2."bar" <> fb1."bar")
left join foobar fb3
on fb1."group" = fb3."group" and
   fb3."timestamp" < fb1."timestamp" and
   fb3."foo" = fb1."foo" and
   fb3."bar" = fb1."bar"
left join foobar fb4
on fb4."group" = fb1."group" and
   fb4."timestamp" < fb1."timestamp" and fb4."timestamp" > fb3."timestamp" and
   (fb4."foo" <> fb1."foo" or fb4."bar" <> fb1."bar")
where fb2."group" is null and (fb3."group" is null or fb4."group" is not null)
group by fb1."group", fb1."foo", fb1."bar"

Explanation: We are searching for the fb1 records for which there is no newer fb2 records with different foo and bar combination, nor older fb3 record with the same combination, or, if such an fb3 exists, then an in-between fb4 also exists with a different combination.

"critical piece of information I'm trying to extract is when I first received the combination"

@Zegarek thanks for pointing that out, I have added the timestamp to the select clause accordingly.

That'd get you an ERROR:  column "fb1.timestamp" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

@Zegarek edited my answer accordingly.

Thanks for addressing these. In my tests it initially seemed like the most performant approach (as long as more parallel workers were made available) but I just noticed it's returning incorrect numbers of results. In this test I created 200k samples in around 4k different groups and this solution is returning 5k rows, suggesting in some cases it's fetching more than one per group.

@Zegarek the line of (fb2."foo" <> fb1."foo" or fb2."foo" <> fb1."foo") was wrong, my typo. Fixing...

@Zegarek edited it. Thanks so much for experimenting with this one and letting me know of the issues you found.

Thanks, that fixed it. It seems that there's some performance advantage window somewhere in the data profile. With 4k groups on 200k rows, it performs worse without more workers, and only catches up to the window approach when given more CPU. On something more capable than db<>fiddle, window function runs 12s on 10M rows on a single worker, while this needs 4min on one, 1min20 when I give it 8 cores, of which it utilises 4-5. Thing is, when tweaking group counts and update repeatability, somewhere under 200k I did see a few cases where this ran 10-30% faster.

You may resort to the old-school way of doing 'distinct on' selection using row_number window function:
select distinct on ("group", foo, bar) * from 
(
 select *, 
   row_number() over (partition by "group", foo, bar order by "timestamp") rnk
 from foobar
) t
where rnk > 1 -- ignore the initial set of values
order by "group", foo, bar, rnk; -- and pick the earliest record

Demo

If you unconditionally skip the latest value (where rnk > 1 -- ignore the initial set of values), you filter out cases where the latest value was the most recent distinct change: demo (should show 33 for group 2, shows 99).

Fair enough. I was not sure whether the OP expects one/zero results  per group or not.
